# Laravel Pint not Running one test on /database

Tags: laravel, laravel-pint

I have an odd issue when working with Laravel Pint on Windows. If I run `php vendor/bin/pint --test -v` I get no issues raised. Pint has fixed them all, including (I can see on the MR in GitLab) various issues in the /database folder.

But when GitLab's CI runs `php vendor/bin/pint --test -v` it finds errors in superflouous PHPDoc comments in the various /database migrations and seeders.

I can check, and see by manual inspection that these are indeed there and should have been removed. As I say, pint has fixed various issues in these files so it's certianly hitting them, and if I run `php vendor/bin/pint .\database\migrations\2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php --test -v` to manuall check one of the files, it tells me there IS an error, and fixes it correctly if I exclude the `--test` parameter.

I don't understand why it's not running one test for one subfolder, when there's absolutely nothing in pint.json that limits any folders in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your local machine is running the same version of Pint. Perhaps the application (and therefore CI) are using a different version of Pint that is applying different rules.

The past few releases of Pint have been tweaking rules a bit as it's still relatively new.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first idea, but they're both definitely using 1.10.0